# Using functions issue

Tags: android

can somebody explain me this, if I have a method which returns boolean, like this

```
public boolean APlusB(int a,b,c){
 if((a+b)==c){
    return true;
 }else {
    return false;
 }
}
```

and then I code something like this

```
ArrayList<Boolean> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.add(APlusB(1,2,3));
 if(APlusB(1,2,3)){
   Log.e(tag,"Success");
 }else{
   Log.e(tag,"Fail");
 }
```

So, in this part I used APlusB function 2 times or that part with if isn't counted?

Thank you.

Comment: First off this code wouldn't compile.  You aren't passing any parameters to the function either time.

Comment: @gabe-sechan Sorry, forgot about that, I've edited my post, please take a look.

Comment: You're calling it twice.  Since you're passing in the same parameters they should both return the same thing.  However the Java compiler may be able to optimize your code and make just one call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You are calling it twice. Doesn't matter how many times u pass the same parameters either for checking or getting value, U are calling that function.

1. `arrayList.add(APlusB(1,2,3));`
2. `if(APlusB(1,2,3)){ .. }`
3. `APlusB(1,2,3)`
4. `arrayList.add(APlusB(1,2,3));`
5. `APlusB(1,2,4)`
   and so on.

*above example I am calling APlusB 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

arraList.add(item) this method return type is void. So you can verify by using size of array list

```
  boolean additem(APlusB)
 {
   int count=arrayList.size();
   arrayList.add(APlusB)
   return (arrayList.size()>count?true:false)
}
```